# How would I get my list item number to go left instead of right? (CSS)

Tags: css

#### Hi~

I'm making a custom code block using the OL tag. I already have counting set up, so how would I make my list number go left instead of right when the number is >= 2 digits? Here's some images:

Current CSS (the font "Code" is defined in @font-face)

```
ol.code {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
  border-radius: calc(0.35rem / 2);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: orange;
  border-width: medium;
}

ol.code li { 
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-family: Code;
  font-size: 25px;
}
ol.code li:before { 
    content: counter(item) "  "; 
    counter-increment: item;
    color: #acacac;
}
```

What I currently have:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PYvx.png)

What I want:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0EAS.png)

Thank You!

Comment: Post your codes in a working snippet instead of images.

Comment: @prettyInPink sure!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine right text alignment, left padding and negative text indentation to achieve this effect.

The exact numbers you will need depends on your font, so you'll have to play around with it a little bit. In the example below, having a text indentation of half the left padding seems to be the magic formula.

Once you have the padding to text-indention radio figured out, you can adjust the numbers depending on how many list items you anticipate having. For example, in order to accommodate 3-digit numbers below, I used

```
padding-left: 3em;
text-indent: -1.5em;
```

But if you were only going to have 2-digit numbers, you could get away with

```
padding-left: 2em;
text-indent: -1em;
```

```css
ol.code {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
  border-radius: calc(0.35rem / 2);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* padding-left: 15px; */
  padding-left: 0; /* NEW */
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: orange;
  border-width: medium;
}

ol.code li {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-family: Code;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ol.code li:before {
  content: counter(item) "  ";
  counter-increment: item;
  color: #acacac;
  display: inline-block; /* NEW */
  text-align: right; /* NEW */
  padding-left: 3em; /* NEW */
  text-indent: -1.5em; /* NEW */
  margin-right: 0.5em; /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<ol class="code">
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum</li>
</ol>
```